# NextJS build using /app (content) + /pages (API) directory

Tags: next.js, build, hadoop-yarn, next.js13

I'm using the recommend `/app/[location]/page.tsx` method for content pages, and as far as I'm aware the `/pages/api/[location]` method is still the recommend way to create an API with NextJS, so that's what I'm using.

When running yarn start, I can access the `/api` pages, but `/customer` for example returns a 404. What am I doing wrong here?

When running `yarn build`, I get the following:

```
Route (app)                                  Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /customers                               9.7 kB          257 kB
├ λ /customers/[id]                          21.7 kB         290 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                87.8 kB
  ├ chunks/364-c3d598881c49c845.js           10.1 kB
  ├ chunks/698-48527a7a00ed2277.js           25.1 kB
  ├ chunks/bce60fc1-cc1897e9b9f8781a.js      50.5 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-66d9fe6a02460cac.js      213 B
  └ chunks/webpack-42b374cbd62c5f26.js       1.82 kB

Route (pages)                                Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /404                                     181 B          75.6 kB
├ λ /api/customers                           0 B            75.4 kB
├ λ /api/customers/[id]/address              0 B            75.4 kB
├ λ /api/customers/[id]/balance              0 B            75.4 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                75.4 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-8883d1e9be70c3da.js     45 kB
  ├ chunks/main-1438612519771f5c.js          28.4 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-b75b9482ff6ea491.js    195 B
  └ chunks/webpack-42b374cbd62c5f26.js       1.82 kB
```

`/customers` should access the customers page, rather than a 404

Comment: There must be something wrong in your page, perhaps show your code or try debugging the component.

Comment: You can create and api folder inside the app directory. That should work.